# IDE Eclipse with Spark SQL connect Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am developing Spark SQL code with the Eclipse IDE. I want to access the tables I have in hdfs, particularly in the hdfs:/data directory. That configuration should develop at the beginning of my program? By default only support me Hive in /tmp.

Thank you

Comment: Aren't you declaring the configuration at the beginning of the program already?

Comment: I do not know what settings should I do